# Pulling all WordPress posts with Advanced Custom Fields Check Box value of X

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a Calender display on a WordPress website. On each day a list of activities that is available ill be show.

At the moment I have it set up so each activity is a new custom post type ('activity') and on the edit page, using Advanced Custom fields and there check box option (field name 'day') you can select monday Tuesday etc.

I can display the days its available on the activity post (i.e 'Football' or 'Swimming') through the following code:

```
<?php
/*
*  Conditional statement (Checkbox value is an array)
*/

    if( in_array( 'tuesday', get_field('day') ) )
    { ?>

        <?php the_title();?>

<?php } ?>
```

But I want all posts to be displayed on a  Summary/Archive page within the correct day - currently set up like so:

```
<div class="day-container">
    <span class="day">Tu<span class="not-mobile">esday</span></span>
    <ul>
        <li class="swimming"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Swimming</li>
        <li class="fitness"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Fitness</li>
        <li class="walks"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Health Walks</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="day-container">
    <span class="day">Tu<span class="not-mobile">esday</span></span>
    <ul>
        <li class="swimming"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Swimming</li>
        <li class="fitness"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Fitness</li>
        <li class="walks"> <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div> Health Walks</li>
    </ul>

</div>

    ... etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of plugging away I managed it, See answer below if anyone gets into the same problem!

```
<?php 

    $weekdays = array(
    'monday' => 'Monday',
    'tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
    'wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
    'thursday' => 'Thursday',
    'friday' => 'Friday',
    'saturday' => 'Saturday',
    'sunday' => 'Sunday',
);
?>

<?php 

    foreach($weekdays as $day):

    // args
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'activity',
        //'meta_key' => 'day',
        //'meta_value' => $day  
        'meta_query' =>  array(
            array(
                'key' => 'day',
                'value' => $day,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )   

);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="day-container<?php echo strtolower(date('l')) == strtolower($day) ? ' active'         : ''; ?>">
<span class="day"><?php echo substr($day,0,2); ?><span class="not-mobile"><?php echo     substr($day,2); ?></span></span>

<ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="<?php echo strtolower(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

</div>





<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```